# Network to network VPN Centos 5

Tags: networking, centos, vpn, ipsec

I am trying to follow "http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-vpn.html#s1-ipsec-net2net"

I have come up with the following 
On local router machine:
in my ifcfg-ipsec0:

```
ONBOOT=yes
IKE_METHOD=PSK
DSTGW=10.5.27.1
SRCGW=10.6.159.1
DSTNET=10.5.27.0/25
SRCNET=10.6.159.0/24
DST=205.X.X.X
TYPE=IPSEC
```

I have /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/keys-ipsec0 file in place.

On Remote Machine in the cloud if have /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ipsec1:

```
TYPE=IPSEC
ONBOOT=yes
IKE_METHOD=PSK
SRCGW=10.5.27.1
DSTGW=10.6.159.1
SRCNET=10.5.27.124/25
DSTNET=10.6.159.0/24
DST=38.x.x.x
```

with its respective /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/key-ipsec1 file.

The DST in both cases are NAT'd external IPs. Is that a problem?

I have made changes for port forwarding as well.

When I try to bring the interfaces up it gives me output "RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument". I am confused now and don't know what more to do?

Any place I can digup what parameters were wrong?

I really appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks and Regards,
Atul.

Comment: I found this: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=192401 - the problem was with my SRCGW. It should be the IP of the "IPSec Gateway" that means the local machine, which is used by the ifup-ipsec as a source ip. Unless someone else has any other inputs I will answer this question in a couple of days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this: bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=192401 - the problem was with my SRCGW. It should be the IP of the "IPSec Gateway" that means the local machine, which is used by the ifup-ipsec as a source ip. Unless someone else has any other inputs I will answer this question in a couple of days.